# What do you understand by this line "dr-- -w- --x file"

Tags: files

As far my assumption it is related to directory but after that i cannot understand the remaining pattern

Answer (score 0):

“dr— -w- --x file”

d: Denotes it's a directory

r - Read Permission

w - Write Permission

x - Execute Permission

First 3 character (apart from "d") denotes permission of owner of file.

Next 3 character tell about permission of user in same group

Last 3 character denotes access for others (not owner, not in same group)

You can refer link to read more about it. 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod